# react native stack navigation - triggering navigation from page that has been mounted, but is in background/not focused

Tags: react-native

I have three screens: Start, A, and B.

The Start screen triggers some actions that pushes A onto the stack. A updates some data. I want the Start screen to see the data update with a useEffect and then, even though it is not currently focused/is in the background, trigger a navigation to B. However, even though the useEffect is running, the `navigation.navigate` call doesn't actually trigger. Why is that?

I tried putting a useEffect like this in the Start screen:

```
// useEffect to handle navigation on data updates
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('this calls again once the data variable updates')
    const nextScreen = determineScreen(data) // this is initially 'A', but once data updates, evaluates to 'B'
    navigation.navigate(nextScreen)
    }
  }, [data, navigation])
```

Once the data updates as a result of user action on `A`, I am seeing the console.logs in the useEffect run. I am also seeing that the `nextScreen` is being evaluated correctly and comes out to `B`. However, the `navigation.navigate` simply isn't calling, and I am not seeing a navigation to `B`.